# Buffer overrun when running in debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, variadic-functions, widechar, printf

When running our game in debug-mode I get a buffer overrun crash - the callstack is bananas (looks like it's stuck in a recursive loop) however I tracked the crash to the following function:

```
std::wstring formatWstring(const wchar_t *first, ...)
{
    wchar_t str[4096];
    va_list marker;
    va_start(marker, first);
    vswprintf_s(str, sizeof(str), first, marker);
    va_end(marker);
    return str;
}
```

which is called in the following fashion:

```
std::wstring gmh = io::lexicon->getString("FE_gamemode_header");
std::wstring gms = io::lexicon->getString(formatString("FE_gamemode_%s", game->getCurrentMapGameMode().c_str()));
m_gameMode = formatWstring(L"%S: %S", gmh.c_str(), gms.c_str());
```

I can't seem to figure out what's blowing this up.. any clues?

Comment: `sizeof(str)` should be `sizeof(str)/sizeof(wchar_t)`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore That should be the answer.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze IDK if that's the actual problem.

Comment: To OP: don't neglect reading descriptions of the functions you're using.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore It could definitely lead to a buffer overrun.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze yeah, you're right, my mind was playing tricks on me. In my head, I though `sizeof(str) < sizeof(str)/sizeof(wchar_t)`, so fewer elements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the call to

```
vswprintf_s(str, sizeof(str)/sizeof(wchar_t), first, marker);
```

You're operating on the wrong size. `wchar_t` doesn't have `char`'s guaranteed of being 1 in size.